# How do I keep IPs in a dockerized Consul cluster on a single node after restart

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I am quite new to Docker and Consul and now trying to set up a local Consul Cluster consisting of 3 dockerized nodes. I am using the `progrium/consul` Docker image and went through the whole tutorial and examples described.
The cluster works fine until it comes to restarting / rebooting.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

`---
node1:
  command: "-server -bootstrap-expect 3 -ui-dir /ui -advertise 10.67.203.217"
  image: progrium/consul
  ports:
    - "10.67.203.217:8300:8300"
    - "10.67.203.217:8400:8400"
    - "10.67.203.217:8500:8500"
    - "10.67.203.217:8301:8301"
    - "10.67.203.217:8302:8302"
    - "10.67.203.217:8301:8301/udp"
    - "10.67.203.217:8302:8302/udp"
    - "172.17.42.1:53:53/udp"
  restart: always
node2:
  command: "-server -join 10.67.203.217"
  image: progrium/consul
  restart: always
node3:
  command: "-server -join 10.67.203.217"
  image: progrium/consul
  restart: always
registrator:
  command: "consul://10.67.203.217:8500"
  image: "progrium/registrator:latest"
  restart: always`

I get message like:

`[ERR] raft: Failed to make RequestVote RPC to 172.17.0.103:8300: dial tcp 172.17.0.103:8300: no route to host`

which is obviously because of the new IP my nodes 2 and 3 get after the restart. So is it possible to prevent this? A read about linking and environment variables but it seems those variables are also not updated after a reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problem until I have read that there is a ARP table caching problem when you restart a containerized consul node.

As far as I know, there are 2 workaround:

1. Run your container using --net=host
2. Clear ARP table before you restart your container: docker run --net=host --privileged --rm cap10morgan/conntrack -F

The owner(Jeff Lindsay) told me that they are redisigning the entire container with this fix built in, no timelines unfortunately.

Source: https://github.com/progrium/docker-consul/issues/26

Comment: This is so. More information:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8795
https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/1465